# NoSuchMethodError at SXSSFWorkbook.dispose() | Apache POI

Tags: java, jar, apache-poi, wildfly, nosuchmethoderror

We are using Apache POI's SXSSFWorkbook implementation to generate large size excel reports in our applications. 
As this implementation puts lots of temporary files in the memory while generating the excel, we are using dispose() method to clean those off from the memory.

Unfortunately, we are encountering NoSuchMethodError for this method. We are using poi-ooxml-3.12.jar version. 
As a first step of verification I checked if there is any conflict in jar versions, but no it looks fine. Also there are no duplicate jar.

We have cluster of servers (WildFly-13) and this piece of code is working perfectly fine in Master server, but failing only in Slaves.

Can anyone help me point out possible issue?

Comment: "working perfectly fine in Master server, but failing only in Slaves": Then determine the differences between master server and slaves. Seems the slaves do not have correct access to at least `poi-ooxml-3.12.jar`. Btw. why using that old `apache poi`version?

Answer (score 0):

you not included the correct version of poi-ooxml-3.12.jar for excel writing.
extract the  jar and check that method you not going to found .

that is thrown at run time.

i have faced similar issue and via replacing the correct jar its worked.

Comment: Method exists in the jar version we are using.